# Some part of my character is not very well lighted

Tags: texturing, camera, light

I have a problem with the lights,because this is a topic that I have never studied well. I don't understand because the scene that I created is not lighted very well. I'm using the sky texture as background in cycles render. I have also placed a sun light on the scene and I have increased its strenght,but it seems that it is not working. Problem is that the facial features,the shoes and the hands of the boy are too dark. Instead,the girl is better lighted...can you give me some suggestion ? thanks.

[image: 1]
[image: 2]

You can find the blender file here :

[blender file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/g1fqdtyn217jumu/equi5.blend?dl=0)

NB : The character models come from blendswap. I have only modified them a little. Credits goes to the original authors.

Answer (score 1):

Even though this is quite a simple mistake beginners only make, we are here to help you and you are here to learn!

As I have seen from your file, you have used a point light as your only light source. If you make this a sun lamp you will have directional light that will emit the whole scene from the same perspective. The point light emits light in all directions from one point. Your characters' faces are casting a shadow onto other parts of the face because the lamp is not shining from the front of the characters. Here's what you can do:

Rotate the lamp on the X-axis towards the characters. Not literally on a 90-degree angle, but on a slight angle. Maybe rotate it like 35 degrees. The light now hits the front of the characters.

You can also add a plane with the surface facing towards the characters from behind the camera. Get it about as long as the space between the characters. Also make it as high as them. You should add a new material using the emission shader. Play around with the strength values until you like it. You can also play with the position of the plane. You can also get it up a little higher than the characters and make it face it their way too to get a little more contrast of the curves of their shape.

I hope this is working out for you. Good luck!

Comment: If he's going to use a sky texture shouldn't he just increase the strength?

Comment: I'm trying different kind of combinations,but I'm not satisfied. can someone modify in some way the blender file that I've attached and send it to me ? So I can explore inside it and I can learn faster ? thanks.

Comment: I tried to apply what you have suggested,but the face,arms and hands of the boy are still very dark,check here : http://imgur.com/a/pXd2Q

Comment: I fixed the problem,but not in the way that you have suggested. The problem was not related to the way which I'd configured the lights,but to the kind of texture that I used. I don't know why,but I used a texture that wasn't lighted by any kind of lamp. I changed them and voila'. it worked. Do you know the reason ?